# TableView not printing any cells (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to just display simple values pulled from my firebase database into a TableView currently. The issue I am getting is that the cells are not being populated with anything currently. I have put in print statements just to ensure that the array is not empty, and it isn't. I am using the following code:

```
    class DisplayTransactions: UITableViewController {

    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    //gets current firebase users
    var userC = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    var pubCount: Int!
    var anArray = [String] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var transRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child((userC?.uid)!).child("PaymentTransactions")

        //for Deposit children
        transRef.child("Deposit").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            //creates enumerator of the snapshot children for
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                self.anArray.append(String(rest.value))

                //printing the rest.value to make sure there are children to iterate through
                print(rest.value)
            }
        })
        //for Withdrawl children
        transRef.child("Withdraw").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            //creates enumerator of the snapshot children for
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                self.anArray.append(String(rest.value))

                //printing the rest.value to make sure there are children to iterate through
                print(rest.value)
            }
        })
        print(anArray)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return anArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellID")

        cell.textLabel?.text = anArray[indexPath.row]
        print(anArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not reloading UITableView after filling up your data source.
You need to do that, every time you change content of an array.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var transRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child((userC?.uid)!).child("PaymentTransactions")

    //for Deposit children
    transRef.child("Deposit").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        //creates enumerator of the snapshot children for
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            self.anArray.append(String(rest.value))

            //printing the rest.value to make sure there are children to iterate through
            print(rest.value)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData() //<<<<<<<<<<<< RELOAD TABLEVIEW
    })
    //for Withdrawl children
    transRef.child("Withdraw").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        //creates enumerator of the snapshot children for
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            self.anArray.append(String(rest.value))

            //printing the rest.value to make sure there are children to iterate through
            print(rest.value)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData() //<<<<<<<<<<<< RELOAD TABLEVIEW
    })
    print(anArray)
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but nothing changes.  Still shows blank cells for a brief second, then goes to an entirely blank page.

Comment: Ahh my mistake, I had misplaced the .reloadData() originally

Comment: Yes you need to keep those inside "blocks" not outside.